# Angularjs with bootstrap alert - keep the alert on screen when scroll down

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, alert, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the example from 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
     <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}"
        close="closeAlert($index){{alert.msg}}>    
    </alert>
    <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

When I'm scrolling down the the alert is disappearing from the screen.
how can I move the alert down when the user scroll down?

Comment: Nothing to do with JS or Angular... this is a CSS question. Your alert tag is open.

Comment: have a look there https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster that's very good solution for non-blocking notification

Comment: position: fixed + z-index in CSS

Comment: DeadCalimero, I suggest you post this as an anwser so I could mark this solution as the correct anwser.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding a class to your alert. Then as @DeadCalimero suggested, you add the following css:

```
.alert-float {
  position: fixed,
  top: 10px,    // adjust if needed
  z-index: 1000 // or higher if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap class 'affix' check this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix,